# Some characters like quotes only appear after pressing spacebar, how to change this?

Tags: 11.10, keyboard-layout

After installing 11.10 the behaviour of my keyboard changed. I now suddenly need to press spacebar after typing some special characters like quotes to make them appear. How can I fix this? This wasn't the case in 11.04.

Answer (score 13):

It sounds like you have a keyboard layout with *dead keys* selected.  In this mode, pressing <kbd>"</kbd> followed by something like <kbd>a</kbd> will generate the character <kbd>ä</kbd>.  Pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> cancels the dead key behaviour to give you a plain quote character.

You can turn off dead keys support as follows:

1. From `System Settings`, open the `Keyboard Layout` control panel.
2. Click the button marked with a plus sign in the lower left of the window, and add the new layout.  For example, if you currently have `English (US, international with dead keys)` selected, add `English (US)`.
3. Remove the old keyboard layout by selecting it in the list and pressing the "minus" button in the lower left of the window.

Comment: Correct. This is also how a spanish or french keyboard works. You press the key and then space to see the letter that you want. +1 for the answer.

Comment: Local access works like a charm. Only have to problem over remote desktop (xrdp). Using mate GUI. Choose a layout won't populate with entries. (Thus an empty Country and Variants pulldown... :/)

Answer (score 4):

Found this question from googling on my issue - having to press tilde twice to get it to print out. I think what James said should work perfectly. However, in case you're not running GNOME - e.g. I'm on Xubuntu - this achieves the same thing:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration

Then you go with one of the generic models, see the difference between 101, 104, 105 keys here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PC_keyboard

I went with 104, no dead keys, en-us. Rebooted and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that this only happens when selecting "English (US) with dead keys". Selecting "English (international AltGr dead keys)" will not require a space for quotes, but typing `AltGr+a` will produce `á`.

Answer (score -1):

There is a also a possibility that while working you pressed 'ctrl' and 'shift' key simultaneously. Press this again to turn of this feature.Hope this may be helpful.
:)