# KDE Umlauts without compose key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, compose-key

I recently switched from Windows to Kubuntu.

I have an US international keyboard (€ sign on key <kbd>5</kbd>).

In order to be able to type Umlauts I have to press the <kbd>compose key</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>+<kbd>vowel</kbd>. This is extremely annoying for me.

I'd like to have the Windows behavior back, that is, Umlaut = <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>+<kbd>vowel</kbd> only, without a compose key.

How can I do this with KDE? So the question is, how can I type umlauts without using a compose key? Is it possible at all?

Comment: How did it know when you wanted 'e instead of é in Windows? On my keyboard layout, ' is a non-caps symbol, so I just need to type compose+'+vowel. I think if you just want to press less keys, the best solution might be to create a custom layout, based on US international, which redefines ' to be a non-caps key so you don't have to press shift: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions?action=show&redirect=Howto%3A+Custom+keyboard+layout+definitions

Comment: 'e is '+space+>e on Windows ...

Comment: Again not exactly what you want, but it might help you to simplify umlaut typing: http://superuser.com/questions/677000/umlauts-on-linux-like-on-mac-us-keyboard

Comment: I think I found it: deadkeys: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68051/some-characters-like-quotes-only-appear-after-pressing-spacebar-how-to-change-t

Answer (score 0):

Only tested on KDE4 at the moment, but assuming you can find the same layout in KDE5 (or any other environment), this should work.

Choose the "English (US, international with dead keys)" layout.
[image]
[image]

Comment: hm. can't find this for KDE5

Comment: Looks like a bug: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=347137